# How do I replace certain text with the respective line number using sed?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, sed

I have a file where certain (not all) lines look like so:

```
Sequence: n
```

I wish to replace `n` with the respective line number.

How can I do it with sed?

Comment: By "do it with sed" do you mean "do it with sed" or "do it with any common tool"? Because people say the former and mean the latter about 98% of the time

Comment: I am specifically curious about sed.

Answer (score 5):

It is very simple with `awk` (thanks to @glenn jackman):

```
awk '/Sequence: n/ { $2 = NR } { print }' input-file
```

Regarding `sed`, I've only been able to do this with a two-pass elaboration (tested with `GNU sed` and with `ssed`:):

```
sed '/^Sequence: n$/{s/n$//p;=;d;}' | sed '/^Sequence: $/{N;s/\n//;}'
```

The first inserts the line number in the row after "Sequence: ", the second joins the two lines.

Comment: I'd write your awk command as: `awk '/Sequence: n/ {$2 = NR} {print}'`

Comment: @glenn jackman: well done, my bad.